# issues when converting web app to https

Tags: node.js, iis, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

My team and I are currently trying to convert a web application to HTTPS on a windows server. We've set up IIS to handle the ports, and are testing with a self-signed certificate. We are currently experiencing a problem where our express calls are timing out to retrieve the data for our app.

Currently the app WILL run on the local host machine after we accept the unsafe site warnings. However, on other machines the app's front-end will load, but data retrieval results in `connection_timed_out`.

The only coding on the app we changed is adding the `pem` files and the following code:

```
var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'keys/privatekey.pem'),'utf 8'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'keys/certificate.pem'),'utf 8')}; 

https.createServer(options,app).listen(9004);
```

Our current suspicion is that the problem lays somewhere with the self-signed certificate and IIS.

Comment: If your IIS server just forwards the request to your node app you don't need https locally because iis is doing the https work between the client and the server and iis just forwars it internally.

Comment: If your front end is loading then your app should be working because its serving static files. Unless the windows server is serving your static files. More log info would help.

Comment: Instead of utf-8 try using Base64 or ASCII ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a member of Obsanity's team. We discovered that we couldn't telnet into the required ports, and forced a group policy update (`gpupdate /force`) on the Windows server.